# scrapy using xpath selector by class result in syntax error

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I try to scrape this webpage https://books.toscrape.com/index.html using scrapy

```
def parse(self, response):
    all_books = response.xpath("//article")

    for book in all_books:
        book_title = book.xpath(".//h3/a/@title").get()
        book_price = book.xpath(".//div[@class="product_price"]/p[@class="price_color"]/text()").get()

        print(book_title)
        print(book_price)
```

will result in:

```
book_price = book.xpath(".//div[@class="product_price"]/p[@class="price_color"]/text()").get()
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this is very strange because this is a standard xpath selector I copied from Chrome inspection tool (which is working there) and I've copied it 1:1 like the instructor did in his lesson, but only I get the error, that did I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change outer quotes type to single quote (or change inner quotes, or escape inner quotes like this `\"`):

```
book_price = book.xpath('.//div[@class="product_price"]/p[@class="price_color"]/text()').get()
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you could just use :

```
    './/p[@class="price_color"]/text()').get()
```

The use of the 2 predicates [ ] is not needed, and using the above will make your code shorter